# How python standrad lib invoke C or C++?

Tags: python, c, interpreter, cpython

The function in **"time.py"** from cpython is almost just "pass" definition. I guess the implement of its function is in **"lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so"**, so I want to know how cpython interpreter invoke ".so" file? I know **ctypes**, but I can't find where "time" module in cpython use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that Python provides an API for C programs (the [Python / C API](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/index.html)), which allows one to define/instantiate Python objects, including functions, in C code (see [extending Python with C](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html)). There is a method called [Py_InitModule](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/allocation.html#c.Py_InitModule) (and variations of that), which make it possible to instantiate a Python module within C code and to register method definitions and set/add fields to it.

In terms of how Python loads "time.so", it probably does so using the [dlopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) C function, which allows libraries to be opened dynamically at runtime (or, on Windows, the equivalent [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx)). Using this approach, it is possible to retrieve a function with a specific name (e.g. Python can enforce that any ".so" file that implements a Python module, must provide an initialization function with a special signature) and then invoke it, allowing the initialization function to register the various definitions.